# Is this result correct ? [ impedance cavity based on emtamaterials using CST Microwave]

Tags: antenna, impedance, microwave

In the contexte of my reaserch about antenna conceptions,
I'm trying to simulate using CST Microwave a cavity antenna based on metamaterial structure and a slot antenna as a GND,However I got as a results:

- Total efficiency near to 130%.
- The impedance decreased from 50 ohm to 28 ohm.

Are those results correct [note that I used a cavity] ? or not?

Comment: Hi there! It might be helpful if you would upload the specific inputs & outputs for your simulation so that you can get specific answers to you question :-)

Answer (score 5):

Antenna efficiency over 130% would mean a perpetual motion machine, so probably not.